# How can I run a function as soon as an element has finished rendering?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, dom-events

I need to set the height of an element based on the height of another element. Let's say that when that element is finished rendering, it's 490px tall.

If I query that other element's height at the beginning of my function inside `$(document).ready()`, it returns 432px.

If I query that other element's height inside a `setTimeout(function, 100)`, it returns about 475px.

If I bump the `setTimeout` up to 150 or so, the element is finished rendering and I get 190. But obviously I can't count on this.

I don't want to wait for the entire page to finish loading, if possible; I want to wait only on this element.

It seems like the `load` event is supposed to work on arbitrary elements, but as far as I can tell that's unimplemented in browsers, or at least in Chrome.

**EDIT**: The element is not an image and (almost certainly) no images will ever be inside the element. It's just a `<div>` with some other `<div>`s and `<p>`s and things in it. The height is apparently getting queried in the middle of the CSS being applied or something. Code samples forthcoming.

**EDIT 2**: [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/75th/YsQrd/) hacked out of my site. (Please forgive the horrid markup; I haven't cleaned up Drupal's output yet.) The fiddle doesn't exhibit the bad behavior I'm trying to correct, though, because the whole snippet gets rendered before the relevant part of the Javascript is run.

Is there a way to do this, or am I stuck with `window.onload`?

Comment: and what is that element ? an image ?

Comment: Can you show us your code?  Preferably in a jsFiddle?

Comment: @Mohammad Yes, or perhaps the element is expanding to fit a loading image?

Comment: As you noticed, an element's dimensions are often dependant on other elements so it isn't reliable to calculate its dimensions before all other elements have been rendered. The window load event is the earliest reliable point when you can be sure the element is at its final dimensions.

Comment: @Leng That's a bit of a premature conclusion. I don't think we can reliably conclude that the element is an image. I agree it is probably an image but the OP needs to clarify before we can come to that conclusion.

Comment: @War10ck I never said it was an image, Mohammad asked if it was one.  All I said, if you'd actually read comments, is that the element -might- be expanding to fit a loading image.

Comment: @Leng My apologies. My intentions were not to cause an argument. I did read the comments. Per your comment you said **Yes**. I don't know how that can be taken in any other context except "Yes it is an image." Until the OP clarifies this fact, (or whether they ever decide to) we can only speculate it is an image. I was just noting this because no one should base answers on the fact that we **think** it is an image.

Comment: @War10ck Ah, my apologies too, I misread your tone.  Thanks for clarifying.  I definitely agree.

Comment: @Leng No problem buddy. All a misunderstanding. Happy coding! :)

Comment: I made an edit with some additional info. Code sample is forthcoming.

Comment: @Leng and others: I added a fiddle with my code, though the fiddle itself does not exhibit the problem I'm trying to solve.

Comment: @War10ck To you as well, friend.  :)  @Trombone:  Did you try using `$(window).on("load", .. )`, as suggested by Frits below?

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
<img src="myImage.gif" onload="loadImage()">
```

Comment: Not every element is an image

Comment: @ejay Things that need to be rendered that don't happen instantaneously (or nearly instantaneously) are usually images. He didn't specify, but the loading image delay is common. This won't work for divs because divs are loaded instantaneously. The content inside them might not be, but if you're populating the content inside the div with functions, then you should be checking to see if that content is loaded with other functions.

Comment: what about he has multiple images inside the said container?

Comment: @Ejay var counter = 0; function incrementLoad(){if(counter == $('img').length){alert("all images are loaded");}else{counter++;}}<img src="myImage.gif" onload="incrementLoad()"><img src="myImage.gif" onload="incrementLoad()"><img src="myImage.gif" onload="incrementLoad()"><img src="myImage.gif" onload="incrementLoad()">

Comment: if he has jQuery then why using obtursive javascript?

Comment: You know he has jQuery because the first thing he mentioned was: $(document).ready()

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use at least `$(window).load()` since you need to wait on additional resources like images and CSS sheets that can affect the dimensions of elements on the page.

`load()` can work on images as well. You should be able to get it right without needing `setTimeout`.

http://api.jquery.com/load-event/ contains a notice that it doesn't work reliably for images.

Comment: `.load` is deprecated as of jQuery 1.8, so it isn't recommended for use.

Comment: Use `.on("load", .. )` then. http://api.jquery.com/category/deprecated/deprecated-1.8/ _This method is a shortcut for `.on('load', handler)`._

Comment: that would be best, but it would probably be helpful if you change it in the answer.